# Bootstrap modal queda debajo de la sombra y no puedo usarlo

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Buenas, tengo un poroblema en mi sitio y es que un modal bootstrap al lanzarlo se abre pero queda como debajo de la sombra digamos. Buscando mucho con el inspeccionador de chrome logre encontrar que al deshabilitar el `position : relative` de los estilos se arregla el problema, el tema es que estos estilos vienen de bootstrap. Hay alguna forma de anularlo desde mi sitio?

Asi esta cuando no funciona digamos

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y de esta forma es como lo arreglo desde el inspector
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: aumenta o agrega al `z-index` del modal a: `z-index: 1041;` así estará encima del backdrop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para las personas que puedan tener este problema, lo solucione buscando con el inspeccionador esa parte que me molestaba y en el css del modal le cree esa clase que ya tiene bootstrap y cambie el valor que era fixed a relative y quedo funcionando

```css
.modal-backdrop{
 position: relative; 
}
```

Comment: ¿No funcionó cambiar el `z-index`?

Comment: No creo que debas usar `relative` para resolver tu problema, los dialogos siempre están en `absolute` o `fixed`. Usar `relative` sólo te estropeará el posicionado de tu modal.

Answer (score 0):

Este código hay que ponerlo en un jquery para solucionar el problema, del modal que se pone de abajo de la sombra

```js
!function(n,o,e){"use strict";e(".modal").appendTo("body"),e("#onshowbtn").on("click",function(){e("#onshow").on("show.bs.modal",function(){alert("onShow event fired.")})}),e("#onshownbtn").on("click",function(){e("#onshown").on("shown.bs.modal",function(){alert("onShown event fired.")})}),e("#onhidebtn").on("click",function(){e("#onhide").on("hide.bs.modal",function(){alert("onHide event fired.")})}),e("#onhiddenbtn").on("click",function(){e("#onhidden").on("hidden.bs.modal",function(){alert("onHidden event fired.")})})}(window,document,jQuery);
```

Answer (score -1):

Siempre se puede utilizar el !important para pisar una propiedad de otra clase que hace conflicto, pero no es recomendable abusar de ello.

Comment: ¿Esto no es más bien un comentario a la pregunta?